# How to set an SKSpriteNode image to fill the screen

Tags: swift, xcode, skspritenode

So far, I have written the following code. Right now, it fills the screen because I set the width and height to specific values.  This method, however, will not make the image the correct size on every other device. I am wondering if there is any way to change the size of an image so it automatically fills up the screen every time, on whatever device.

```
func backgroundScene() {
let constructionSite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background Image")
constructionSite.size = CGSize(width: 425, height: 900)
constructionSite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
constructionSite.zPosition = -1
addChild(constructionSite)
}
```

Comment: Instead of `CGSize(width:height:)`, you can just get the size from `frame.size`

Comment: You do not want the image to be the same size as the screen on every device.  You will end up with weird scaling issues.